# Alma's annotations to Chapter 14 of Ulysses

Tags: james-joyce, ulysses

(If this question does not fit this site, let me know and I'll delete it).

I'm considering buying the "Annotated Edition" of *Ulysses* published by Alma Classics. I was wondering about the nature of these annotations, specifically for Chapter 14, "Oxen of the Sun".

This chapter is well known to be almost impenetrable, and **I would like to know whether the annotations attempt to help read and understand the sentences in it**, and how/why they mean what they are usually assumed to mean in summaries of *Ulysses* (as opposed to, say, just elucidate the allusions in the chapter). This is related to [a previous question I posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/annotations-to-ulysses-that-help-understand-its-sentences-literally).

I enjoyed very much deciphering the sentences in this chapter which I managed to decipher, and I'd be very happy for help with the rest.

Comment: Whether the annotations "help at all" will be dependent on how much you understand by yourself, how much background knowledge you have, how much time you devote to trying to figure out how it all works, etc. - I'm not sure this is answerable.

Comment: The annotations are visible [via the "Look Inside" feature on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ulysses-Alma-Evergreens-James-Joyce/dp/1847497764?asin=1847497764&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1) — I suggest you take a look and see. But the Kindle edition is only £4.99 so if it were me I would just take a punt.

Comment: @bobble By "help at all" I meant to ask whether there's such an attempt (most editions I looked at didn't). GarethRees: Thanks, but I don't have an e-reader...

Comment: @Ell Lack of an e-reader shouldn't stop you from reading the annotations via Amazon's web site!

Comment: @GarethRees Really? That's great to know! Although there are a few editions I'm hopeful might help me, so nevertheless I'd need to do some digging before choosing on which one to gamble, even it it's not much of a gamble :)

Comment: Ell, if you have an amazon account, you can read Kindle books on any device you can download an app to, apparently you can also use a 'cloud reader' without downloading anything, but you do need an amazon account. https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-read-kindle-books-on-pc?r=US&IR=T

Comment: @Spagirl: You need to use the "search for a word or phrase" feature (the magnifying glass in the top left) to see pages after the initial sample. [Here's a copy of page 726](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qLUc.png) which has notes for the "Oxen of the Sun" chapter as requested by the OP.

Comment: @GarethRees Oh, right enough. I hadn't realised that. Thank you